# PHP Query Error #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 2

Tags: php

First creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `db_mcms`.`pages` (
        `page_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
        `page_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL, 
        `page_title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
        `viewable` TINYINT NOT NULL,
        `permission` TINYINT NOT NULL 
        ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Now trying to insert stuff:

```
INSERT INTO  `db_mcms`.`pages` (
        `page_id` ,
        `page_name`,
        `page_title`,
        `viewable`,
        `permission`
        )
        VALUES  ("1", "edit", "Edit Your Website", "1", "0"),
                ("2", "index", "Edit Index Example" "1", "0"),
                ("3", "newpage", "New Page", "0", "0");
```

Gives me the error:

```
 #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 2
```

What am I doing wrong guys?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a comma here:

```
"Edit Index Example" "1"
```

Replace this with

```
"Edit Index Example", "1"
```

Comment: @Sem if his answer solve your problem, please mark it as the answer